# Seeking help to create a linear syntax for the tree package in LaTeX similar to prooftree

Tags: tree, latex

Hello LaTeX community,

I am currently working on a project that requires the use of LaTeX to create trees. I am familiar with the `prooftree` package, which offers a linear syntax for creating proof trees. However, I would like to use the `tree` package instead, but with a similar linear syntax.

In `prooftree`, an inference tree is created by specifying the nodes in order and the number of elements inferred. For example, the tree `[A [B] [C [D] [E]]]` is noted as follows:

```latex
\hypo{E}
\hypo{D}
\infer2{C}
\hypo{B}
\infer2{A}
```

I would like to achieve the same linear syntax using the `tree` package. I understand that this might require creating new commands or environments, and I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to accomplish this.

Thank you in advance for your help!